# unrecognized selector sent to class, along with -> terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

```
-(void)sliderClicked 
{
   [self.window bringSubviewToFront:btntemp];
   [self.window bringSubviewToFront:sliderView];

   if (sliderView.frame.origin.x==0)
   {
       btntemp.hidden = YES;
       [self performSelector:@selector(presentLeftMenuViewController:)]; // Getting Error in this line
   }
   else
   {
       btntemp.hidden = NO;
       [self performSelector:@selector(presentLeftMenuViewController:)]; // Getting Error in this line
   }
}
```

above Method is in `AppDelegate.m` , I am getting error like

> > +[RESideMenu presentLeftMenuViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10e7902b8
> >     libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception.

RESideMenu classes are from Third party, Method -> presentLeftMenuViewController is from them
will Anybody Please Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Your class `RESideMenu` doesn't implement a class method called `presentLeftMenuViewController`

Comment: RESideMenu Classes are Third Party taken from github there would not be prob with them. may b any issues with navigationscontrollers or rootviewcontrollers ?

Comment: Where is `presentLeftMenuViewController` defined?

Comment: presentLeftMenuViewController is defined in  RESideMenu.m

Comment: There isn't a problem with the class, but there is a problem with the way you are using it. `presentLeftMenuViewController` is an instance method, not a class method, so it needs to be called on an *instance* of `RESideMenu` as you do in the first case, not how you are doing it in the else

Comment: Still Same error if i write    [self performSelector:@selector(presentLeftMenuViewController:)];

Comment: Update your question showing the implementation of the `presentLeftMenuViewController:` in the same .m file as the code you have already posted.

Comment: And why are you using `performSelector` instead of calling the method using the normal way to call a method? And if the selector ends with `:` then it takes one parameter. But your call to `performSelector` doesn't attempt to pass an argument.